# Solr autocompletion with NGrams and MappingCharFilter

Tags: solr

I want to implement an auto completion search with solr. The user is searching for names of persons. The auto completion is done by NGrams. This is working properly, so when I search for "Caro" i find "Caroline". What i want to do now is a Char Mapping. The user should find "Caroline" by entering "Karo" in the search. So "k" will be mapped to "c". When I search with the config below i get an empty result by searching "Karo" or "Karoline" ("Caro" works).

I have created a mapping.txt with following content:

```
"k" => "c"
```

Here is my field configuration:

```
<fieldType name="string_wildcard" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" side="front"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="/home/martin/mapping.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you are using "k" => "c", which will only replace the lowercase k to c.

you need to add lowercase filters to the filter chain, to make it case insensitive.

```
<fieldType name="string_wildcard" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>    
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" side="front"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="/Users/jayendrapatil/solr/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```